# thresh in dropna for DataFrame in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3))
df1.iloc[:4,1] = np.nan
df1.iloc[:2,2] = np.nan
df1.dropna(thresh=1 ,axis=1)
```

It seems that no nan value has been deleted.

```
    0     1     2
0   0   NaN   NaN
1   3   NaN   NaN
2   6   NaN   8.0
3   9   NaN  11.0
4  12  13.0  14.0
```

if i run

```
df1.dropna(thresh=2,axis=1)
```

why it gives the following?

```
    0     2
0   0   NaN
1   3   NaN
2   6   8.0
3   9  11.0
4  12  14.0
```

i just dont understand what thresh is doing here. If a column has more than one nan value, should the column be deleted?

Comment: "If a column has more than one nan value, should the column be deleted?". No. If the column has N non-null values or more, it should not be deleted. Convince yourself that this isn't the same thing.

Comment: I generally don't put a number there, (axis=1 thresh=0.7 * len(data_frame))=> Keep all those columns with 70% Non-na values. I think it makes more sense like this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`thresh=N` requires that a column has at least `N` non-NaNs to survive. In the first example, both columns have at least one non-NaN, so both survive. In the second example, only the last column has at least two non-NaNs, so it survives, but the previous column is dropped.

Try setting `thresh` to 4 to get a better sense of what's happening.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. I thought the threshold controlled number for nan values. I was wrong. Thresh refers to non-nan values.

Comment: May I ask why this argument does not appear to be listed in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop) for this method but still works?

Answer (score 0):

**thresh** parameter value decides the minimum number of non-NAN values needed in a "ROW" not to drop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This will search along the column and check if the column has atleast 1 non-NaN values:

```
df1.dropna(thresh=1 ,axis=1)
```

So the Column name 1 has only one non-NaN value i.e 13 but thresh=2 need atleast 2 non-NaN, so this column failed and it will drop that column:

```
df1.dropna(thresh=2,axis=1)
```